# Animating a dynamically added view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

Ok so I am adding views to my layout programatically and then animating them, the views seem to add correctly but when I start the animation it doesnt seem to work here is the code :

```
                Random random = new Random();
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) animationLayout;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //params.topMargin = screenHeight;
            params.leftMargin = random.nextInt(screenWidth);

            vg.addView(imageView,params);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.musical);
            imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            float randomSize = random.nextFloat() * (1.5f - 0.5f) + 0.5f;
            imageView.setScaleX(randomSize);
            imageView.setScaleY(randomSize);


            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(imageView, "translationY",0, -screenWidth);
            animator.setDuration(15000);
            animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    Log.e("removed", "true");
                    vg.removeView(imageView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
            animator.start();
```

What could be causing the animation not to work? the view gets removed after the animation is over though so i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer looks like I was using `ObjectAnimator.ofInt()` instead of `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat()`

Comment: Have you looked at `LayoutTransition` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html for an alternative solution?

Comment: @liminal This is not a layout transition, I am dynamically adding multiple ImageViews in a layout in the background of the displayed content to give the affect of a moving background